# Rails: How to handle Thread.current data under a single-threaded server like Thin/Unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thread-safety, thin, unicorn

As Thin/Unicorn are single threaded, how do you handle Thread.current/per-request storage?

Just ran a simple test - set a key in one session, read it from another -- looks like it writes/reads from the same place all the time. Doesn't happen on WEBrick though.

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def get
    render text: Thread.current[:xxx].inspect
  end

  def set
    Thread.current[:xxx] = 1

    render text: "SET to #{Thread.current[:xxx]}"
  end
end
```

Tried adding `config.threadsafe!` to application.rb, no change.

What's the right way to store per-request data?

How come there are gems (including Rails itself, and tilt) that use Thread.current for storage? How do they overcome this problem?

Could it be that Thread.current *is* safe per request, but just doesn't clear after request and I need to do that myself?

- Tested with Rails 3.2.9

## Update

To sum up the discussion below with @skalee and @JesseWolgamott and my findings--

Thread.current depends on the server the app is running on. Though the server might make sure no two requests run at the same time on same Thread.current, the values in this hash **might not get cleared between requests**, so in case of usage - initial value must be set to override last value.

There are some well known gems who use Thread.current, like Rails, tilt and draper. I *guess* that if it was forbidden or not safe they wouldn't use it. It also seems like they all set a value before using any key on the hash (and even set it back to the original value after the request has ended).

But overall, Thread.current is not the best practice for per-request storage. For most cases, better design will do, but for some cases, use of `env` can help. It is available in controllers, but also in middleware, and can be injected to any place in the app.

**Update 2** - it seems that as for now, draper is uses Thread.current incorrectly. See https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/390

**Update 3** - that draper bug was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to store stuff in session.  And if you want something really short-living, see [Rails' flash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash).  It's cleared on each request.  Any method which relies on thread will not work consistently on different webservers.

Another option would be to modify `env` hash:

```
env['some_number'] = 5
```

BTW Unicorn is not simply single-threaded, it's forking. The new process is spawned on each request (despite it sounds scary, it's pretty efficient on Linux). So if you set anything in Unicorn, even to global variable, it won't persist to another request.

Comment: Session is not necessarily in-memory (and doesn't clear every request) and flash is essentially session that clears after next request. Isn't there a way to store per a single request? Just saw `warden`'s code which uses `Rack::Request` to store stuff. Is it safer?

As I mentioned, there are plenty of gems including `rails`, `tilt` etc that use `Thread.current` -- how come?

Comment: Warden's approach is good thing, too, especially if it makes you feel better :D  Actually, in Rails you can access this hash using `env` (e.g. `env['elados_number'] = 5`.  Warden is not Rails-only gem, so it can't rely on Rails features.  Also, I am not sure how good `flash.now` is in storing more complex objects.  I was not aware that `Thread.current` is used in Rails internally.  I'm not sure how it works across webservers, I'd stick to `env` or `flash.now`.

Comment: And how would I access that `env` from a non-controller code?

Comment: Why you'd like to do it? Controllers are meant to process requests.  You can pass object from controller to view, just assign it to instance variable of controller.  You rather don't want it in models, cause models are very unrelated to requests. Where do you want to access it? Middleware?

Comment: Let's say I have a justified reason :) I still don't get how many gems and code samples use Thread.current (for example, to store current_user) while it's not safe at all. Are they all wrong or am I holding it wrong?

Comment: Could it be that Thread.current *is* safe but just doesn't clear after request and I need to do that myself?

Comment: Yeah, you were quicker.  Some webservers, for example Unicorn, won't suffer from this cause they are forking.  When it comes to `config.threadsafe!`, it has nothing to do with that.  It generally preloades everything because Rails' autoloading is not thread-safe.

Comment: Please provide a single example where popular gems are using Thread.current... It's really not done.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Grepping `tilt`'s source code (indirect dependency of Rails): `lib/tilt/template.rb`.

Comment: @skalee --- Tilt's use is pretty black magic and definitely not recommended for cases where you don't need extreme performance. It's hard to come up with a use case where it's a good idea.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Also Rails IdentityMap and its flag. the IdentityMap#use method actually sets the value of the Thread.current and when done it sets it back to what it was.

Comment: I ended up creating a Middleware that sets a Thread.current var and cleans it after request done. I wonder if this is considered Thread safe or not. Will test and post code.

Comment: Another limitation came to my mind: `Thread.current` won't work with evented programming like `em-synchrony`.  And please think again if you really need access to request stuff outside controller (not just pass as parameter to model methods or sth), because it really smells like bad design.

Comment: @skalee well, to elaborate on what I'm doing - it's an API (grape based) that shows a list of users and whether the current user follows each (perspectival attribute). 1st usage for Thread.current is to store/retrieve current_user. Then, instead of executing N queries for current_user.following?(user) I gather all the users that are in the response and query once (in a draper presenter), then assign follow states behind the scenes before it's going to rendering. You could say it's kinda like IdentityMap with different purpose.

Comment: @elado -- there's no reason to use Thread.current for that purpose. You really really really can have a much simpler design that's threadsafe. YMMV, but you've been warned for sure.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott regardless of what I do, are you saying that Thread.current is dangerous and should never be used, not by Rails/tilt any other, ever?

Comment: @elado I am saying you should not use it unless you have an extreme example. You end up with a global variable, which I would also recommend not using and is a common code smell.

Comment: Now that I understand the nature of Thread.current, which is per *thread* and not per-request (like .NET's HttpContext.Current) I'll look for a different, cleaner solution. Thanks!

Comment: @elado Solution from Warden you proposed is really good. `env` is per-request hash, Warden uses it to store arbitrary objects. `env` object is defined in Rails controllers and middleware. I believe `env` object is defined in Grape too (at least they wrote that in readme).

Comment: @skalee `env` is still not available on non-controller context. Btw, Draper gem also uses `Thread.current`. I agree that a better design will help but don't get how popular gems use it if it's allegedly not safe. Maybe the only non-safe issue is that values don't get cleared after each request, so they better be cleared before each request. And then it's safe to access this hash, because the server makes sure no two requests are executed with the same thread concurrently. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: @elado — It's available in middleware, controller and Grape. "because the server makes sure no two requests are executed with the same thread concurrently. Correct me if I'm wrong" — I am not sure, but I think in Rails it's true. It's certainly not true in evented applications, but they're rather uncommon in Ruby. I'm not exactly sure what do you want to do, try if you dare, I guess it will work, but it is very unclear and smells.

Answer (score 0):

While people still caution against using `Thread.current` to store "thread global" data, the possibly correct approach to do it in Rails is by clearing-up the `Thread.current` object using Rack middleware. Steve Labnik has written the [request_store](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) gem to do this easily. The source code of the gem is really, really small and I'd recommend reading it.

The interesting parts are reproduced below.

```
module RequestStore
  def self.store
    Thread.current[:request_store] ||= {}
  end

  def self.clear!
    Thread.current[:request_store] = {}
  end
end


module RequestStore
  class Middleware
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      RequestStore.clear!
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

Please note, clearing up the *entire* `Thread.current` is not a good practice. What request_store is basically doing, is it's keeping track of the keys that *your app* stashes into Thread.current, and clears it once the request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the caveats of using `Thread.current`, is that for servers that reuse threads or have thread-pools, it becomes very important to clean up after each request.

That's exactly what the [`request_store`](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) gem provides, a simple API akin to `Thread.current` which takes care of cleaning up the store data after each request.

```
RequestStore[:items] = []
```

Be aware though, the gem uses `Thread.current` to save the Store, so it won't work properly in a multi-threaded environment where you have more than one thread per request.

To circumvent this problem, I have implemented a store that can be shared between threads for the same request. It's called [`request_store_rails`](https://github.com/ElMassimo/request_store_rails), and the usage is very similar:

```
RequestLocals[:items] = []
```